# Scraping a Sloppy Node

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping a "sloppy" node that includes multiple elements of the same data. The code below scrapes **city-dates** from a page that lists record albums. I only want the first city-date instance for each album, but I'm not sure how to write the code so that only the **first** city-date instance is returned.

```
library(rvest);library(stringi);library(stringr)
citydate <- read_html("https://www.jazzdisco.org/atlantic-records/catalog-1200-series/") %>%
    html_nodes(".date") %>% html_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not too much hierarchy in the page you are scraping. This means you will need to look at other structure. It seems that each date is preceeded by a `h3` header. Knowing this we can build an index to grab the values you are after.

First grab all of the `h3` and `.date` nodes:

```
nodes <- read_html("https://www.jazzdisco.org/atlantic-records/catalog-1200-series/") %>%
  html_nodes("h3,.date")
```

Now for the index. We want to find where a `h3` is followed by a `.date`. I have used the `html_name` and a `paste` function to test for the structure but you can build this however you wish.

```
index <- c()

for (n in 1:(length(nodes) - 1)) {

    if (paste(html_name(nodes[n]), html_name(nodes[n+1]), sep = "_") == 'h3_div') {
      index <- c(index, n)
    }

}
```

Now using the index we can get the `.date` nodes. My test has matched the `h3` node so we have to add 1 to get the `.date`

```
citydate <- nodes[index + 1] %>% html_text()
```

Comment: did you use packages other than `rvest` for this solution? I'm getting an error with `html_nodes("h3,.date")`   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Ben, not an addition package but a typo. I was missing the `%>%` between `read_html` and `html_nodes`. I have edited code above to fix

Comment: Thanks much @mrjoh3 !